# how to delete strings before / in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with thousand of lines of file names with absolute path.

```
Mar 18  2013 drawable/midplayer/
Mar 18  2013 drawable/midplayer/btnSelected.png
Mar 18  2013 drawable/midplayer/btnUnselected.png


desired output:
Mar 18  2013 btnSelected.png
Mar 18  2013 btnUnselected.png
```

I want to take out the complete path and just want the file names. How to accomplish this? Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you limited to notepad++ ? Else there is lots of ways to do this with the shell environment in the unix or linux systems.

Comment: Thanks carl. I'm new to this so indentation was all wrong

Comment: @TheDemz No i m not. the file was created in windows. how can i accomplish this in unix

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use notepad++, two replaces with regular expressions turned on might work.

Try these without the double quotes.

This will replace the first part of your path.

```
Find What: " ([^\s])+/"
Replace With: " "
```

This removes all lines without a . in them

```
Find What: "^[^\.]+\r\n"
Replace With: ""
```

Comment: I tried it on one file and it worked like a charm. You saved my day buddy.Thanks much

Comment: Travis can i also insert a comma between Date and the filename using regex?

Answer (score 0):

Your files are formatted very nicely, so one regex can do the trick:

```
Find: ^(.*\s+)[^\s]+/([^/]+)$
       |-----|               this is the timestamp ($1)
              |-----|        this is the excluded part
                     |-----| this is the file name ($2)
Replace: $1$2
```

Comment: can i also insert a comma between Date and the filename using regex?

Comment: @cedrajin21 Sure, just change the Replace to `$1, $2` and possibly move the `\s+` out of the first group so the find is `^(.*)\s+[^\s]+/([^/]+)$`